# Kernels of powers of linear operator $T$ a partition of the space implies $T^N=0$ for some $N$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:X\to X$ a continuous linear operator. Assume that for all $x\in X$ there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $T^nx=0$. Then there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $T^N=0$.

My proof:

By assumption we have $X=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ker(T^n)$. Since $T$ and therefore $T^n$ are continuous, $\ker(T^n)=(T^n)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Therefore, by the Baire cathegory theorem, there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\ker(T^N)$ has non-empty interior. In particular it contains an open ball $B(x_N, \epsilon)$ and hence a closed ball $\overline{B}(x_N, \epsilon)$. Now let $x\in X, x\ne 0$ and without loss of generality $||x||=1$ (else consider $x/||x||$). Then $x_N+\epsilon x\in \overline{B}(x_N, \epsilon)\subset\ker(T^N)$ and therefore $T^N(x_N)+\epsilon T^N(x)=T^N(x_N + \epsilon x) = 0$ which implies $T^Nx=0$, from which the claim follows.

This is my first time working with the BCT, therefore I would appreciaty any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine, everything is O.K.